# Prevent CKEditor from removing span elements

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

If I paste

```
<p class="foo">Some text: <span class="bar"></span> More text.</p>
```

into the editor as source then the `span` element will be removed when switching back to text edit mode.  Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in [this forum post](http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/Prevent-removal-of-empty-span-tags).

Before creating my CKEditor (I personally am using the jQuery adapter, but this config option should work either way) I set `CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty.span = 0`.

Also see [this doc page](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dtd-property-S-editable).